# The exact number of Givens rotations required to describe an orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

Let $U\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be an orthogonal matrix, i.e., $U^T=U^{-1}$.

Any orthogonal matrix can be written as a product of ${n \choose 2 }= \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$  [Givens rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation), i.e., $U=R_1\cdots R_{n(n-1)/2}$.

However, some orthogonal matrices might be represented with fewer Givens rotations.
Is it possible to compute the smallest number of Givens rotations needed to represent an orthogonal matrix? Furthermore, if we know a given orthogonal matrix can be represented with few Givens rotations, is it known whether one can the usual $O(d^3)$ time of matrix decomposition algorithms like QR decomposition?

Comment: The general question of finding "the smallest number of real numbers needed to represent an orthogonal matrix" doesn't make much sense.  For instance, I could represent any orthogonal matrix $U$ with the number $1$ if I define a function $f$ for which $f(1) = U$. The reason we need a certain quantity of numbers is because we want a "coordinate system" for a *collection* of matrices of a given type.

Comment: If you're referring specifically to your Givens rotation representation: with an idea similar to my approach on [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3789495/81360), we can conclude that the number of Givens rotations required is at least $d - 2m$, where $m$ is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I was referring the the Givens rotation representation. I updated the question to hopefully reflect this.